# timezoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST" return America/Chicago (CDT) value

Tags: ios, timezone

I want to find the timezone for "Saskatoon, Saskatchewan, Canada" (Whose timezone is CST), so I am using the abbreviation CST on following method:

```
var timezone = NSTimeZone.init(abbreviation: "CST")
print(timezone)
```

OUTPUT:

> America/Chicago (CDT) offset -18000 (Daylight)

Why am I getting a value of CDT while I am passing CST?

Can anyone help me how can I get correct value using `timezoneWithAbbreviation:` method for CST abbreviation of "Saskatoon, Saskatchewan, Canada" ?

Comment: Chicago uses both CST and CDT... as do various other time zones. Basically, don't use zone abbrevations... they're horrendously ambiguous :(

Comment: @JonSkeet, i thought question was not about Chicago, but about Saskatchewan. And OP, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Saskatchewan

Comment: @user28434: The OP was asking why they got Chicago when asking about CST - and I pointed out that Chicago uses both CST and CDT, so it's not an unreasonable outcome.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quickest response, So conclusion is "timezoneWithAbbreviation:" method should not be used at all times, right ?

Comment: @PragneshPatel, it should be used, but not expect that your location will have same timezone with this abbreviation all year around, or there will be 1:1 map between timezone and your location.

Comment: @PragneshPatel: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimezone/1387248-init)  states that it is ambiguous and you are discouraged from using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try initialising your `NSTimeZone` with [location `tzname`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimezone/1387215-init) (for `TimeZone` [use this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timezone/2293505-init)) instead of `abbreviation`.

For `Saskatchewan` it would be `"Canada/East-Saskatchewan"`, `"Canada/Saskatchewan"` or `"America/Regina"`.